# Failing testing database connection in php

Tags: php

I've set up a database using MAMP. 
When I try the following test, I only receive a blank page. Fairly new to this, and I've tried different suggestions found on the web with no luck. 
Tried using both port and socket.

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'test';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;
$socket = "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock";

$link = mysql_connect(
   "$host:$socket",
   $user,
   $password
);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(
   $db,
   $link
);

if (!$link){
echo "ERROR";
}
else {
echo "Success";
}
mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: add ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); to see the error at the top of your script.

Comment: Since you're fairly new to this: **don't learn `mysql_`**! Learn PDO or `mysqli_` instead! And start by learning how to use *prepared statements* http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - there's no use in learning it the wrong way first, so avoid `mysql_`

Comment: @Qirel thats what i said in my answer and got -1 for it

Comment: @NeinrappeurZaki Well, it's not an answer to the problem OP is having. We don't know what that is, because we haven't got an error-message, so it could be any number of things.

Comment: Yes , i understand , what i said is that i also advised Him to use PDO instead of mysql which is a way insecure and Old now ,

Comment: Since the page is blank you probably are getting an error check your logs. If PHP 7 you aren't going to be able to use `mysql_*`..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Would you like to try PDO ?!

```
<?php
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasenamehere";
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $option = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );

    try {
        $connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass,$option);
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
    catch (PDOException $r) {
        echo 'Failed' . $r->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: helped me a long way, see my answer below for what I ended up with

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";



try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;test", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: what are you getting as error?this code Will work and if details are right it will echo the success message

Comment: @NeinrappeurZaki This one worked, and I got the "Connected succesfully" message

Comment: nice to here so , So use PDO better , it is more secure